# Please help me with TCL

Tags: tcl

I’m trying to print information from below procs.

The main proc should wait and printed after proc a1 and proc a2 has finished.
Proc a1 will store into a variable if exist information,
Proc a2 will add or store information to same variable.
I don’t know how to make it work if possible to do that.
Any advice please.

```
proc main { var } {
    puts $var
}

proc a1 { var } {
    upvar $var d1
    set d1 [list 100=50 101=60]
}

proc a2 { var } {
    upvar $var d2
    set d2 [list 102=100 103=300]
}
```

I don’t know how to make it work if possible to do that

Answer (score 0):

Defining the procs is not enough...you actually need to call the procs too!
In addition, your proc definitions for a1 and a2 cannot be in a simple one line string like you did.   You need to separate the `upvar` and `set` commands with a newline or a semicolon.

```
# Proc definitions
proc main {var} {puts $var}

proc a1 {var} {
    upvar $var d1 
    set d1 [list 100=50 101=60]
}

proc a2 {var} {
    upvar $var d2
    set d2 [list 102=100 103=300]
}

# Now call the procs
a1 foo
a2 foo
main $foo
```

This is a pretty weird set of procs though.  When `a2` is called after `a1`, the variable it sets will overwrite any previous value.   `a2` is not *adding* and new information.